# What is the difference between Sweep All and Sweep Single?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, sweep-transaction

The Monero source code specifies [sweep single](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/8286f07b265d16a87b3fe3bb53e8d7bf37b5265a/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server_commands_defs.h#L835), and [sweep all](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/8286f07b265d16a87b3fe3bb53e8d7bf37b5265a/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server_commands_defs.h#L835) in its RPC Server Commands [section](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/8286f07b265d16a87b3fe3bb53e8d7bf37b5265a/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server_commands_defs.h). What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is documented:

[sweep_all](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#sweep_all)

> Send all unlocked balance to an address.

[sweep_single](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#sweep_single)

> Send all of a specific unlocked output to an address.

So the latter just sends a single output, which is useful if one needs to disassociate linked outputs.